# Want to call a functionality on window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to call functionality in `window.onbeforeunload` as below,

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        getMyApp("mySwf").cancelFunction(); 
  }
```

But the problem is window is getting closed before the functionality gets called. Could somebody help in fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the action you are performing is done synchronously in the `onbeforeunload` handler, then it seems to work. The browser performs your action and then closes.

If the action is asynchronous, i.e. you trigger an event that is handled in another thread, or you set up a timer to fire later, then it will likely be ignored because the window sends an event and closes immediately. (By the way, if you are talking to a plug-in, the action which looks synchronous in your code may be implemented asynchronously in the plug-in, for stability purposes or whatever).

One option is to display a pop-up message in the `onbeforeunload` handler and hope that the action you are performing gets completed while the user looks at the message.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    getMyApp("mySwf").cancelFunction(); 
    alert("Please wait while the file is saved.");
}
```

Another way is to prevent the window from closing. The only way to do it in a web browser is to display a confirmation dialog. Some parts of the dialog message are predefined by the browser, but you can add a piece of your text. The user will be able to close the window anyway, but you can recommend to not close it. Also, it may happen that your task, even if asynchronous, gets completed while the user looks at the message.

To display a predefined confirmation dialog:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    getMyApp("mySwf").cancelFunction(); 
    event.returnValue=true;                // display confirmation message
}
```

To display a confirmation dialog with the addition of your text:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    getMyApp("mySwf").cancelFunction(); 
    event.returnValue="If you close the window, unsaved edits will be lost.";
}
```

After the action you launched is done, you can close the window programmatically.

Comment: I have already tried with these. But that will result a wroing user interface . The purpose of   getMyApp("mySwf").cancelFunction(); is to cancel a transaction if the user closes the browser close  in a particular screen. In other screens it should no happen(this I handled in flex itself) . So If I add a comment like ( alert("Please wait while the trnsaction is cancelled."); it will show pop up even if the transacion is not cancelled.

Comment: If I tries the second scenario  A confirm pop up will come . Before the cancel action will alrady happen . And in that confirm popup if the user click a cancel the user will stay in the page and transaction will get already cancelled...which is wrong

Comment: Is there any way other than popups which will make the browser to wait for some time so that it should get some time to execute this function call

Comment: In the first scenario, before showing the alert, you can check whether the transaction has to be canceled. In the second scenario, when the user stays on the page, and then the transaction is canceled, you can check that cancelFunction succeeded and close the window programmatically from your code. Maybe you will have to create a timer, for example, to wait 0.5 seconds and then close the window.

Comment: How to create a timer in javascript? so  that It will call that and make the browser to wait for some time and then close. I should  not show a pop up basically.

Comment: For timeouts use the [setTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx) method. But it will not allow you to delay window closing. A HTML page can't prevent the user from closing the window, I guess for protection from spam and malware. Also... It seems that it's not possible to create a timer in the `onbeforeunload` handler.